# MySQL slow first query for key limit 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, myisam

I have a 500mb table and perform queries to that for a specific key. Since the table reached over 400k rows the first query is approx 3 sec and the follwing very fast, down to 0.001 sec.

Can I solve this with a better table structure and without increasing the database memory?

The table and keys are set as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `dist_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `title_under` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `pub` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pub_place` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `edition` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
  `holdings` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `rating_g` float(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `rating_r` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_change` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `isbn` (`isbn`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_title_under` (`title`,`title_under`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `author` (`author`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `isbn_title_title_under_author_date_edition_subject` (`isbn`,`title`,`title_under`,`author`,`date`,`edition`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=492755 ;
```

Explain of the mentioned query gives:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE id =304243
LIMIT 1

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          mytable const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 8   const   1
```

Show index of the table gives:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM mytable

Table       Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment
mytable 0   PRIMARY 1   id      A   492753  NULL    NULL        BTREE    
mytable 0   isbn    1   isbn    A   492753  NULL    NULL        BTREE    
mytable 1   tit..   1   title   NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   tit..   2   title.. NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   author  1   author  NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   isbn_.. 1   isbn    NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   isbn_.. 2   title   NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   isbn_.. 3   title.. NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   isbn_.. 4   author  NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   isbn_.. 5   date    NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT     
mytable 1   isbn_.. 6   edition NULL    1   NULL    NULL        FULLTEXT
```

Comment: does it does this no matter what the first query is? it sounds to me that it may be some type of authentication problem. I am not positive thats possible, but its definitely something i would look into if i was in your shoes.

Comment: what about adding an index to the id column

Comment: is myisam, is the table frequently get updated?

Comment: @Johnny Craig It occur for the described query the first time per id. I.e select id = 1 (3 s.) select id = 1 (0.01 s.) select id = 2 (3 s.).

Comment: @reggie id is an primary index, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @ajreal yes it is updated monthly but posts are deleted inserted daily around 2 a.m. Could it be a cause?

Answer (score 0):

Try to warmup the cache manually before your first query. Check out [How to manually build mysql cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010144/how-to-manually-build-mysql-cache).